ESP32-S3 pericodically connect wifi
In my application it's necessary to send some data to a web server at regular intervals (~5min). The rest of the time the wifi should be dormant and only some sensor measurements have to be executed. Since the sensors are temperature dependent, the wifi can't just be left on, because the board and enclosure will heat up due to the high heat of the esp32. Also, the corresponding sensor libraries (MOX/VOC) must be continuously fed with sensor values. Therefore sleep modes are not an option. The general idea is to raise CPU frequency and connect wifi only when needed, and disconnect and lower the frequency the rest of the time just to perform sensor tasks.
I found code on how to re-initialize the wifi library after usage of light sleep and tried to use it just in a loop.
Here is the code snipped. The setup() contains only initialization of the serial line
void loop() {
  int state = 0;
  WiFi.disconnect(false);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  delay (200); 
  Serial.print("Begin: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.begin(ssid, pass));
    
  uint32_t last = millis();

  while(state != WL_CONNECTED && ((millis()-last)<20000)){
    state = WiFi.status();
    Serial.print(state);
    delay (100); 
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    
  WiFi.disconnect(true);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
  delay(10000); // For testing, in real-world it will be 5min

}
First after boot, the state will change from 6 (Disconnected) to 0 (IDLE) and 3 (Connected) within 2 seconds and a valid IP is printed out
The second and all following times, the state will remain at 6 (Disconnected) for multiple seconds, and then switch to 1 (NO SSID AVAILABLE) where it remains until 20s timeout.
If the esp is reset, the connection will work again. Also when i implement deep sleep, it will always work
What could be the issue?

try putting WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF) before WiFi.disconnect(true)

i tried but no change
